# Getting Large amount of data from an api

Tags: java, api, rest

I am calling a Restful api which returns more than 100 000 records.How can I handle this huge amount of data at client side? I don’t want to get all records at once.

Comment: 1 lakh = 100.000 units. Just to clarify.

Comment: Is the restful API yours? Can't you implement pagination logic somehow?

Comment: Well, the answer is kind of obvious.. If you don't want to download all records, you need to filter it, either by paging as Claudio suggests, or by using search queries, such as `title=xkcd`. What do you want to know more specifically, because the question is very broad at the moment

Comment: @claudio  yes it is restful API.But i can implement pagination login

Answer (score 4):

If you are the owner of the restful API, then redesign it to support paging. And request information by smaller parts using page number.

If you are not the owner of the API, then implement a mediator server-side service, that works like a cache with paging support. And the client works with this mediator service, sending requests with page number and gets smaller parts of data.

---

**UPDATE**

Let say your service that returns huge amount of records is named as "Black Box Service".

I suggest to create additional service (let it's name is: "Mediator servie") that gets all requests from the client, handles them, via sending requests to "Black Box Service", caches results and returns information to the client.

Check the image below:

[image: schema]

Assume the mediator service address is: `http://www.yourserver.com/mediatorservice`

Then API of this mediator service should support the following parameters:

`pageNumber` - number of requested page 
`recordsPerPage` - records per one page

and an example request to this mediator service will look like that:

`http://www.yourserver.com/mediatorservice?pageNumber=1&recordsPerPage=25`

This request tries to get the first page (pageNumber = 1) with 25 records on this page (recordsPerPage = 25) from the mediator service.

Mediator service has its own database for caching purposes. If client requests records inside of the range: `1 .. 100 000` then mediator service requests the first big piece of data from the "Black Box service" and stores this piece of data in its own database.

And all other consecutive requests will be served using this cached data block in the mediator service database.

If there's a request in range `100 001 ...200 000` then mediator service gets another huge data block and stores it in it's own database (if it was not done before). And uses this stored data to serve requests from the clients.

Depending on the nature of the information it may require to deal with cached information in different ways. Some information may be cached for a long time, some cannot.

There are many caching java frameworks exist, check for them to choose the one that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.i am not the owner of the api. Can you please explain more on mediator service side service. How this can be achiceved? Please Help

Comment: I will update my answer with more detailed information. I will do it soon.

Comment: @julikaZen please check the update of my answer.